# Unions of closed sets [Topology, S.Willard, exercise 3F]

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

---

Can anybody gives me a hint to show that

> for a family $C_\lambda,\lambda\in\Lambda$ of closed sets in some metric space $X$ such that $d(C_{\lambda_1},C_{\lambda_2})\geq\epsilon$ for all $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$, where $\epsilon$ is a fixed positive integer, then $\cup_\lambda C_\lambda$ is closed?

Also, I am confused about the hypothesis: how can $d(C_{\lambda_1},C_{\lambda_2})\geq\epsilon>0$ when $\lambda_1=\lambda_2$? Does the author mean "for all $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$"? Can we construct an example of a finite, countable, uncountable family of closed sets for which the hypothesis of result is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that implicitly $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ must hold. 
Define $C = \cup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} C_\lambda$.

Suppose $x \in \overline{C}$. Let $r > 0$ be such that $r < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then $B(x,r)$ intersects at most one $C_\lambda$ by the distance property, and it intersects at least one, by being in $\overline{C}$. So there is a unique $\lambda_0$ such that $B(x,r)$ intersects $C_{\lambda_0}$ for all such $r$, and this implies that $x \in \overline{C_{\lambda_0}} = C_{\lambda_{0}} \subseteq C$, and we are done.

We can use singleton sets in a discrete metric space to get any size example we want.

Comment: Do you know any examples in the reals? I am trying to get an intuition to why this result should hold. Thanks!

Comment: Closed intervals like $[2n, 2n+1]$, for $n$ in the integers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the author wants $\lambda_{1}$ and $\lambda_{2}$ to be distinct.

For an element $x$ in the closure of $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}C_{\lambda}$ a sequence $\left(x_{n}\right)$ exists with
$x_{n}\in\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}C_{\lambda}$ and $d\left(x,x_{n}\right)\rightarrow0$.

Then some index $N$ exists with $n\geq N\Rightarrow d\left(x,x_{n}\right)<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$.

Then for $n\geq N$ we find $d\left(x_{N},x_{n}\right)<d\left(x_{N},x\right)+d\left(x,x_{n}\right)<\epsilon$.

This - if $x_{N}\in C_{\lambda_{0}}$- implies that $x_{n}\in C_{\lambda_{0}}$
for $n\geq N$.

This reveals that $x$ is the limit of a sequence in the closed
set $C_{\lambda_{0}}$ so that $x\in C_{\lambda_{0}}\subseteq\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}C_{\lambda}$.

Proved is
now that $\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda}C_{\lambda}$ is a closed set: it contains every $x$ in its closure.